# UrlRewriting.net in Umbraco redirects 6 times

Tags: c#, redirect, umbraco, urlrewriting.net

I have an Umbraco website and i now started using the Urlrewriting.net that comes with it.

Now it seems that all redirect pages are loaded 6 times after 1 click.
The Page_Load event get's hit 6 times on a page that is loaded through a redirect and a 'normal' (of course) has only hits this event once.

I'm using extensionless pages in Umbraco and my redirect rule looks like this:

```
<add name="Category"
     virtualUrl="~/cat/(.+)/(.+)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/category/?CategoryId=$1"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

If i change the virtual url to one that has a .aspx extension, catch that one with the rewriter and redirect, then i don't have this problem.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: did you set <add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true" /> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this had nothing to do with Umbraco. The problem was caused by a component called NivoSlider which kept loading the default page of our website when there was no image url available.. 
Stupid problem with a somewhat crazy effect, but i thought i'll mention it here to close this question and to let the Umbraco guys know that they didn't do such a bad job ;)